# Iterating over split string in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

Let's say I have a string:

```
"ab bc cdv gf
ed    aqb ahf sd
abcdef
```

I want to
a) Split it by `' '` and/or `'\r\n'`, `'\t'`
b) Iterate over newly created list of these substrings, split by separators and match each of them to some criteria (for example, only choose words starting with `'a'`, aka `["ab", "ahf", "abcdef"]`

Note: also we can't use `Str` or any other additional libraries.

I came up with some sort of this code:

```
let f g =
  String.split_on_char ' ' g
  |> List.iter (fun x -> x);;
```

Obviously though, it shows an error. And even if it worked, it wouldn't have split out the `'\r\n'`. Instead of `List.iter` I could have used `List.map (fun x -> x)`, but I will just get the split (by `' '` character only) list of substrings. So now another question: how can I use

```
"match (something?) with
| ..."
```

in this case? I see no way in adding match into the code above. Do we use the reverse `|>` and `List.iter` in this case or is there another way I'm not aware of?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple approach: let's just keep splitting on whitespace characters we want to split on, use `List.concat_map` to maintain a "flat" list, and then reject empty lists.

```
let s = "ab bc cdv gf ed aqb ahf sd abc\r\ndef" in
let split = String.split_on_char in
split ' ' s 
|> List.concat_map (split '\n')
|> List.concat_map (split '\r') 
|> List.filter ((<>) "")

(* Result:
 * ["ab"; "bc"; "cdv"; "gf"; "ed"; "aqb"; "ahf"; "sd"; "abc"; "def"] 
 *)
```

You might also use your regular expression library of choice and split on `\s+`, but apparently that isn't allowed.

You could also break this out into a function using a left fold, and supply the characters to split on as a string.

```
let split_on delims str =
  String.to_seq delims
  |> Seq.fold_left (fun acc delim -> List.concat_map (String.split_on_char delim) acc) [str]
  |> List.filter ((<>) "")
```

```
utop # split_on " \t\r\n" s;;
- : string list =
["ab"; "bc"; "cdv"; "gf"; "ed"; "aqb"; "ahf"; "sd"; "abc"; "def"]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer, that clarified a lot of things. Is there a way to match each of the resulting strings to some value, so that we could sort out strings starting with a, for example?

Comment: `List.filter` works nicely and if you're using OCaml 4.13 or later, you have `String.starts_with`.

Comment: Also, is it possible in this case in general to use a structure "match x with 
| y ...
| z ..." etc, or is it not an option ?

Comment: You cannot use `match` to match parts of a string the same way you would elements of a list, no.